# Jmeter JSON Extractor retrieve the second item from last of a list

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a JSON response like below

```
{
    "queryStartDate": "20170523134739822",
    "queryEndDate": "20170623134739822",
    "Rows": [
        {
            "hasScdHistoryOnly": false,
            "Values": [
                       "1",
                       "53265",
                       "CO"
            ]
        },
        {
            "hasScdHistoryOnly": false,
            "Values": [
                       "1",
                       "137382",
                       "CO"
                      ]
        },
        {
            "hasScdHistoryOnly": false,
            "Values": [
                       "1",
                       "310824",
                       "CO"
                      ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using Jmeter's JSON Extractor post-processor to receive the second value from the last of the 'Values' list. i.e. 53265, 137382, 310824.

I've tried to use `$.Rows[*].Values[-2:-1]`, and `$.Rows[*].Values[(@.length-2)]`, according to Stefan's introduction: http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2, but neither of them are working. Would you please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe JMeter is using JayWay JSON Path library, so you should be looking for the documentation [here](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) instead.

---

In general I would recommend using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as an alternative to JSON Path Extractors, both are applicable for basic scenarios only, when it comes to advanced queries and operators their behaviour is flaky.

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the request which returns above JSON
2. Make sure you have "groovy" selected in the "Language" drop down and "Cache compiled script if available" box is ticked
3. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   def values = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.parse(prev.getResponseDataAsString()).read('$..Values')

   values.eachWithIndex { val, idx ->
       vars.put('yourVar_' + (idx + 1), val.get(val.size()-2))
   }
   ```
4. It should generate the following JMeter Variables:

   ```
   yourVar_1=53265
   yourVar_2=137382
   yourVar_3=310824
   ```

   which seem to be something you're looking for.

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

Using `View Results tree`'s JSon Path Tester I could see that the following expression you used for extracting the values were not correct (correct for online [JSONPath Online Evaluator](http://jsonpath.com/) but not working for JMeter)

Used Expression: `$.Rows[*].Values[-2:-1]`

Output from JSon Path Tester: `No Match Found.`
[image]

Used Expression: `$.Rows[*].Values[(@.length-2)]`

Output from JSon Path Tester: `Exception: Could not parse token starting at position 16. Expected ?, ', 0-9, *`[image]

If the expression `$.Rows[*].Values[1]` is used it extracts the desired responses.

Used Expression: `$.Rows[*].Values[1]`

Output from JSon Path Tester:

```
 Result[0]=53265
 Result[1]=137382
 Result[2]=310824
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Adnan, I am currently using this method as a workaround. I am wondering in Jmeter's JSON extractor, is there actually a way to select backward from the last item. In this scenario it's fine to select forward from the first one. But there are situation the JSON is not normalized but selecting backwards is needed.